# Do the complex zeros of the sum/difference of these series all reside on the line $\Re(s)=\frac12$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, sequences-and-series

The following series seems convergent for all $s\in \mathbb{C}$:

$$\displaystyle f(s):=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(n+s)^{n+s}}$$

The function itself does not appear to have any real or complex zeros, however numerical evidence suggests that all zeros of:

$$f(s) \pm f(1-s)$$

reside on the line $\Re(s)=\frac12$. Their density apparently increases in a quite regular manner.

[image]

1) Could this be proven? When using the finite series $\sum_{n=1}^N$, the claim seems to hold for each $N$.

2) Could there exist a functional equation between $f(s)$ and $f(1-s)$? The only relation I found so far is that $f(-1)=f(1)$.

**EDIT:** A partial result on the second question. Based on Joro's findings below and realising that for integers and half-integers an infinite number of terms could be cancelled out when adding or substracting $f(s)$ and $f(1-s)$, the following reflective formulae hold:

For all integers $s \in \mathbb{Z}$:

$$f(s)+f(1-s) +\sum_{n=0}^{2(s-1)} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{(s-n)^{s-n}} =0$$

For all half-integers $s+\dfrac{1}{2}$ with $s \in \mathbb{Z}$:

$$f(s)-f(1-s) +\sum_{n=0}^{2(s-1)} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{(s-n)^{s-n}} =0$$

The non-alternating series $\displaystyle g(s):=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+s)^{n+s}}$ has one formula for integers and half-integers:

$$g(s)-g(1-s) +\sum_{n=0}^{2(s-1)} \frac{1}{(s-n)^{s-n}} =0$$

Comment: If you want to define this for all $s\in\mathbb C$ directly by the series, you have to be more precise about the powers (a choice of logarithm is involved).

Comment: Christian, you are referring to the branch cut of the natural log, right? For the Maple package I used to check convergence for complex values, this is the principle branch between $\pi$ and $-\pi$.

Comment: Yes, $(n+s)^{n+s}=\exp ((n+s)\log (n+s))$, and you have to say which value of $\log$.

Comment: I doubt my computation is correct, but one should expect some relation like $f(1-s)=-f(-s)+\dfrac{1}{(1+s)^{(1+s)}}$ to hold.

Comment: If you always take values from one fixed interval of length $2\pi$ for the imaginary part of the $\log$, then you have no chance of producing a holomorphic $f$.

Comment: Read $(1-s)$ instead of $1+s$ in my previous comment.

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT** Due to confusing XRay and programming mistake, I erroneously claimed real zeros. Root finding didn't found any zeros off the line.

---

Very partial answer for functional equation.

For integer $s$, $\{1,f(s),f(1-s)\}$ appear linearly dependent
over the rationals with high precision.

Let $K=f(s),K_2=f(1-s),K_3=1/s^s,K_4=(K-K_2+K_3)^2$.

$$s=2, 1+4K+4K_2=0$$
$$s=3, 131-108K-108K_2=0$$
$$s=4, 36059+ 6912K+ 6912K_2=0$$
$$s=5, -695877463+ 21600000K+ 21600000K_2=0$$
$$s=6, 168087904001+ 583200000K+ 583200000K_2=0$$
$$s=7, -1639334733641495543+ 480290277600000K+ 480290277600000K_2=0$$

And in addition for $s=3/2, K^{2} - 2 \, K K_{2} + K_{2}^{2} + 2 \, K K_{3} - 2 \, K_{2} K_{3} + K_{3}^{2} - 2=0$.

...And with the help of Agno's observation, $s=5/2,8503056K_4^4 - 61096032K_4^3 + 202411224K_4^2 - 171663192K_4 + 252460321$

I *suspect* for $s$ half integer there is non-trivial algebraic dependency.

Comment: Really nice, Joro! The coefficients 4, 108, 6912,... seem to follow https://oeis.org/A107048 , so the next one for $s=6$ would be $\pm$2332800000. The constants at the beginning don't seem to appear in a Sloane integer series.

Comment: @Agno for $s=6$ I get: $$168087904001+ 583200000*f(6)+ 583200000*f(1-6)=0$$ which is 4 times of your conjecture.

Comment: Thanks Joro. Note that I started experimenting with the function $g(s):=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+s)^{n+s}}$, but that also induces a single complex pair of zeros off the critical line. The alternating version $f(s)$ doesn't seem to have any complex zeros off the line and i.m.o. had therefore more 'beauty'. Also tried to find a pattern linking integer values $g(n)$ and $g(1-n)$ and I believe it has exactly the same 'weights' ($b$) as you found for $f(s)$ however the initial offset values ($a$) are different: $1,9,139,36571,-468908713,136638677249$ for $n=1..6$ and $a+b*g(n)-b*g(1-n)$.

Comment: @Agno I consider significantly changing the question after a counterexample bad practice IMHO.

Comment: Joro, I am sorry when I have upset you by making this change. No bad intentions here and I made explicit comments about the change in the edit reason as well as in the OP text. Having said that: are you absolutely sure the graph with the real zeros is correct? I have tried to replicate it and it keeps looking differently with no zeros. For the function $f(s)-f(1-s)$ you would expect zeros on the positive real axis if they show up on the negative axis as well (as in your graph). I get imaginary values (I guess Maple makes a certain branch cut here) for values of $s<-1$.

Comment: The Sloane series for the 'weights' above is https://oeis.org/A061464 i.e. $1, 4, 108, 6912, 21600000, 583200000, 480290277600000, 31476303632793600000,...$, which is the denominator of $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^s \frac{1}{(n)^{n}}$ for positive integer values of $s$.

Comment: @Agno I am not sure it is correct. Computed it with sage and mpmath.  I get $f(-1)=-0.21656948928786...$

Comment: @Agno My claim about real zeros was wrong, sorry. Root finding didn't found zeros off the line. I edited.

Comment: No worries, Joro. I will (only slightly :-) ) change the OP to remove the comment on the zeros to avoid confusion.

Comment: @Agno do you confirm the relations (including 3/2) as written now?

Comment: Yes, have checked all integers and get the same results. Have not checked the 3/2 but will do later today.

Comment: Have now also tried the formula for $\frac32$ (hence also for $\frac12$) and it works! Intriguing formula and agree that it might be extendable to all half (positive) integer values. Note that you can simplify your equation to: $(K-K_2+K_3)^2 =2$ so that its zeros occur when
$K_3= -K+K_2 -\sqrt{2}$ and $K_3= -K+K_2 +\sqrt{2}$. Since $K_3(\frac12)=\frac{1}{(\frac12)^\frac12}=\sqrt{2}$, the latter gives the trivial solution for $s=\frac12$.

Comment: @Agno with the help of your observation there is conjecture for $s=5/2$, edited.

Comment: Joro, checked and can confirm that I get the same result for $\frac52$. Note that this formula also works for $-\frac12$. Since $\frac32$ pairs with $\frac12$ and $\frac52$ pairs with $-\frac12$ we might conjecture that $\frac72$ will pair with $-\frac32$...

Comment: Think I found the formula for the functional equation at integer values of $s$:

$$f(s)+f(1-s) +\sum_{n=0}^s \frac{(-1)^{s+n}}{n^n} + (-1)^s \cdot \sum_{n=1}^{s-2} n^n\,=0$$

I guess it could be made a bit more elegantly. Pretty sure a similar reflexion formula exists for the 'non-alternating' form $g(s)$ I described in my comment above.

Comment: @Agno What do you mean by **pair**? For s=7/2 I get degree 8 relation with large coefficients, but the leading coefficient is `2^24 3^24 5^40`

Comment: s=7/2,x=K_4:  `43095327221832275390625000000000000000000000000*x^8 + 540747652373424755859375000000000000000000000000*x^7 + 3405812446046421231530273437500000000000000000000*x^6 + 13462328052874546030018347890625000000000000000000*x^5 + 151921888616411550355704470164089843750000000000000*x^4 + 831220396588475843745514907923600541625000000000000*x^3 + 2500290021726801782533956270362134606625317500000000*x^2 + 3836341067122277488338378199369917555269627731800000*x + 80496352602954281998112712816740167835338103480593921`

Comment: Joro, I meant that I expect both $s=\frac72$ and $s=-\frac32$ should give $0$ in your formula. Tried to reproduce the $s=\frac72$ with your formula above but was unsuccesful. Are you sure all $\pm$s are correct?

Comment: @Agno I am not sure. For me it vanishes for both 7/2 and -3/2. Might have done something wrong though. Btw, I get $K_4(7/2)=K_4(−3/2)$ modulo errors.

Comment: Joro, I can confirm your $\frac72$ (and $-\frac32$) formula works now. Had set my accuracy at too few digits...

Comment: Have now found two clean reflexive formulae which are actually pretty trivial since most terms of the series $f(s)$ and $f(1-s)$ cancel when added or subtracted.


For integers $s \in \mathbb{Z}$:
$$f(s)+f(1-s) +\sum_{n=0}^{2(s-1)} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{(s-n)^{s-n}} =0$$

For all half-integers $s/2$ with $s \in \mathbb{Z}$:
$$f(s)-f(1-s) +\sum_{n=0}^{2(s-1)} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{(s-n)^{s-n}} =0$$

And for $\displaystyle g(s):=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+s)^{n+s}}$ there is a single formula for both integers and half-integers:
$$g(s)-g(1-s) +\sum_{n=0}^{2(s-1)} \frac{1}{(s-n)^{s-n}} =0$$

Comment: @Agno I suggest to put these either in the question (maybe better) or in an answer. They might be special case of something more general, not sure.

Comment: @Agno Do you have relation for something other than integer or half integer? I couldn't find such.

Comment: Joro, I tried hard to find one, but none so far. You need some form of annihilation of the infinite terms. What I did try was to use the n-th prime instead of $n$ (except for the $(-1)^n$) and that version also generates a (different but also regular) pattern of all zeros lying on the critical line $\Re(s)=\frac12$. Unfortunately could nice values at integers nor did I find terms cancelling out. Now busy trying to produce the Hadamard product of the complex zeros to reproduce $f(s) \pm f(1-s)$ for the prime version.